# TVirtualStringTree - How to enable drag when clicked on any area of selected row?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have a VST with `toFullRowSelect` (with a few columns). I would like to enable drag & drop on the nodes.

The problem is that you can start draging the node/s only if you click direcly on the node *caption*. if the click was made on the row selection but not on the node caption, the drag operation will not start and `OnDragAllowed` wont fire.

The MCVE is simple. drop a `TVirtualStringTree` (name it `VST`) on the form and add `OnCreate`, and `OnDragAllowed` for the VST:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VST.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions := VST.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions + [toFullRowSelect];
  VST.RootNodeCount := 5;
end;

procedure TForm1.VSTDragAllowed(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; var Allowed: Boolean);
begin
  Allowed := True;
end;
```

Now, if you click on a node caption, the drag operation starts, but not if you try to drag other area of the selected node.

How can this be resolved? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include **toFullRowDrag** option into the **MiscOptions** option set:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VST.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions := VST.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions + [toFullRowSelect];
  VST.TreeOptions.MiscOptions := VST.TreeOptions.MiscOptions + [toFullRowDrag];
  VST.RootNodeCount := 5;
end;
```

The **toFullRowDrag** option is in the source code described as:

> Start node dragging by clicking anywhere in it instead only on the
>   caption or image. Must be used together with toDisableDrawSelection.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that option.

Comment: Thank you! I've just modified formatting (to fit to style I'm using :)